# How to move I18n folders of WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internationalization, directory-structure

When building my WPF application all internationalization/locale folders are put inside the folder of the executable.

```
/MyApp
/MyApp/de
/MyApp/fr
/MyApp/otherSpecialFolder
/MyApp/...
```

The problem is that this mixes up with some other folders. Is it possible to put the internationalization into a separate folder and let the Wpf app search there instead? For example:

```
/MyApp
/MyApp/i18n/de
/MyApp/i18n/fr
/MyApp/otherSpecialFolder
/MyApp/...
```

This problem occurs not only for own localization ressources but also when adding thirdparty controls like Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You just have to add probing element into your App.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="i18n"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

probing element specifies the path where assemblies are searched for.

Comment: Is it also possible to say that the dependency assemblies should "copy" their dlls there?